# Why cant i move my drop-down list on Python Ktinker

Tags: python, tkinter, button, move, positioning

I wish to move my drop down menu to the upper left.
But when i try to padx and pady nothing is happening.

[image: image of my program]

```
       global text
       self.text = tk.Text(root, bg='black', foreground="white", height="15")
       self.text.pack(padx=0, pady=75)
       self.text.delete('1.0', tk.END)
       self.text.insert(tk.END, "Opps, not yet connect OR no files to be read....")

       self.variable = StringVar(root)
       self.variable.set("Temperature")  # default value
       self.w = OptionMenu(root, self.variable, "Temperature", "Mazda", "three")
       self.w.pack()
```

Comment: `pack(anchor='nw', ...)` ? But all may depends how you add other elements. Besides you add `Text` with `pady=75` so you created margin between `Text` and `OptionMenu`. You may use `pady=(75,0)` to create margin only above `Text`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As default elements are centered and you need `anchor='w'` to move element to the left (`west`)

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

txt = tk.Text(root, bg='black')
txt.pack(pady=75)

om_var = tk.StringVar(root, value='Hello')
om = tk.OptionMenu(root, om_var, 'Hello', 'World')
om.pack(anchor='nw')   # north, west - top, left

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Or you can use `fill="x"` (or `fill="both"`) to resize to full width

```
om.pack(fill='x')
```

[image]

But there is also other problem - in `Text` you used `pady=75` so you created margin between `Text` and `OptionMenu` and you would need `pady=(75,0)` to remove margin below `Text`

```
txt.pack(pady=(75,0))
```

[image]

---

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

txt = tk.Text(root, bg='black')
txt.pack(pady=(75,0))

om_var = tk.StringVar(root, value='Hello')
om = tk.OptionMenu(root, om_var, 'Hello', 'World')
om.pack(fill='x')

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation bro. it worked very well.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using `place()`, instead of `pack()`.